# kafka between two bolt of Storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have an application which have multiple bolt and single Spout. My streaming data is coming very fast in spout and goes to first bolt. In first bolt it take about 50sec time for processing on single tuple and then goes to second bolt. In second bolt there is also complex processing so it is also taking 20sec for a single tuple, but my spout getting data very fast. My question is between two bolt there is any queue which hold the data like kafka. or have to implement kafka between two bolt. or any other approach, where processing time of single tuple is 40-50sec and coming data streaming is very fast.

Thanks

Comment: Storm uses a lot of internal queues. See http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/ for an overview. There should be no need to implement any buffering by yourself.

Comment: how about increating the parallelism for bolts? on a second thought you might want to consider [storm drcp](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Distributed-RPC.html) but not sure if that will fit your need

Comment: storm is about real time processing not batch processing. Most of the time you should try to not have bolts with latencies > 1 sec. Threads could become starved, heartbeats could be missed, timeouts could occur. If it is that long, maybe storm is not suited for your use-case, consider using spark or maybe flink with kafka.

Comment: Storm is not good for what do you want. If a single tuple is taking 40-50seconds to be processed Storm is not for your use case. By the default Storm behavior it to fail tuples which are not fully processed within 30 seconds.

Comment: In this scenario , what should I have to use?

Comment: do you require real time stream processing?

Comment: Yes, working on Personality and Sentiment analytics on twitter streaming

Comment: I'm afraid that taking over 10secs can meet stream processing. 
Btw, you can spread your tuples to multiple workers / executors of bolt, which can process many tuples at the same time, though it doesn't reduce  complete latency.